# Save input fields with the help of a button

Tags: javascript, html

I would need a little help with my script. The user can edit the table cells manually through input fields if something goes wrong.
This works also so far already.
But now I want to save the data that has been typed in with a confirmation button and write it there. The input fields should then also disappear again.
How can I realize this?
The entries also disappear after double clicking the edit button. How can I prevent this?

My codes and approaches:

***JavaScript:***

```js
<script>
    const button = document.querySelector('button');
    const dropdown = document.querySelector('[name="table-rows"]');

let storedEditData = [];

button.addEventListener('click', function () {

const tableRow = document.querySelector('#tableLKW').rows[dropdown.selectedIndex + 1];

for (let i = 0; i < tableRow.cells.length; ++i) {
  const item = tableRow.cells.item(i);
  
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('class', 'your-input-class');
  input.setAttribute('data-cell-id', `${dropdown.selectedIndex + 1}-${i}`);
  input.value = item.innerText;

  storedEditData = tableRow.cells;
  
  item.innerHTML = '';
  item.appendChild(input); 
  


}
});
</script>
```

***JavaScript:***

```js
<script>

button.addEventListener('click', function() {



});
```

***HTML:***

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
<label for="table-rows">Choose a table row:</label>
<select name="table-rows" id="table-row">
    <option value="row1" id="choice1">Table Row 1</option>
    <option value="row2" id="choice2">Table Row 2</option>
    <option value="row3" id="choice3">Table Row 3</option>
    <option value="row4" id="choice4">Table Row 4</option>
</select>
<button>Edit</button><button>Save</button>

<table id="tableLKW" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-dark">
    <thead class="thead-light"> 
        <tr>
            <th style scope="col"><p align="center">position</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">number</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">driver's name</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">vehicle identification</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">status</span></th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">phone</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">short code</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">gate</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">empties</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">track</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">priority</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">from</th>
            <th scope="col"><p align="center">to</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td><p align="center">1</td>
        <td><p align="center">Example Number</td>
        <td><p align="center">Example Name</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder vehicle identification</td>
        <td>placeholder status</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder number</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder code</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>placeholder empties</td>
        <td>placeholder track</td>
        <td>placeholder priority</td>
        <td>placeholder from</td>
        <td>placeholder to</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p align="center">2</td>
        <td><p align="center">Example Number</td>
        <td><p align="center">Example Name</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder vehicle identification</td>
        <td>placeholder status</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder number</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder code</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>placeholder empties</td>
        <td>placeholder track</td>
        <td>placeholder priority</td>
        <td>placeholder from</td>
        <td>placeholder to</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p align="center">3</td>
        <td><p align="center">Example Number</td>
        <td><p align="center">Example Name</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder vehicle identification</td>
        <td>placeholder status</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder number</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder code</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>placeholder empties</td>
        <td>placeholder track</td>
        <td>placeholder priority</td>
        <td>placeholder from</td>
        <td>placeholder to</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p align="center">4</td>
        <td><p align="center">Example Number</td>
        <td><p align="center">Example Name</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder vehicle identification</td>
        <td>placeholder status</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder number</td>
        <td><p align="center">placeholder code</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>placeholder empties</td>
        <td>placeholder track</td>
        <td>placeholder priority</td>
        <td>placeholder from</td>
        <td>placeholder to</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it would be better if you also included the html needed for that script to run with no errors

Comment: it's not strictly the correct answer to your question but did you consider the option to use the attribute `contenteditable="true"` in the `table`? in that case its content will be editable and you'll already have an editable grid that you could transform to a javascript object or serialize it json.

Comment: the answer is yes but it's not as easy. Once you have the table filled with content created by the user, you need a strategy to serialize that data, store it somewhere and load it up in case you wish to represent on screen that same data. The point being that if you reload the page, that data gets lost and the table reset its state. You'd need to store that data and retrieve on demand and that would be needed even if you used your previous approach.

Comment: the scenario described in your question isn't wide enough to include the storage details .. you didn't talk about database nor any backend server. So I suppose your only option is using Web Storage API that will let you save some info in the browser. Is that what you need?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the complete html document demoing the concept of saving and loading user edited table content into and from the local storage.

The `tbody` element is `contenteditable` and there are actions you can trigger like: empty, save and load.

The strategy is just storing and setting back the whole tbody innerHTML content using the following statements:

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value);
localStorage.getItem(key);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #tableLKW thead th {
            background: lightgray;
            padding: 0.15rem 0.25rem;
        }

        #tableLKW tbody tr td {
            border: solid 1px lightgray;
            padding: 0.25rem;
            max-width: 15rem; /*max 15 characters width*/
            word-wrap: anywhere; /*ensure word wrapping so cells dont expand while user types input*/
        }

        button {
            font-size: 1.25rem;
            padding: .25rem 1rem;
            margin-right: 1rem;
        }
    </style>
    <script>

        function loadTableContentFromLocalStorage(){
            const table = document.querySelector("#tableLKW tbody");
            table.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('tableContent');
        }

        function saveTableContentIntoLocalStorage(){
            const table = document.querySelector("#tableLKW tbody");
            localStorage.setItem("tableContent", table.innerHTML);
        }

        function emptyTableContent(){
            const table = document.querySelector("#tableLKW tbody");
            table.innerHTML = "";
        }

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
            document.getElementById('save_table_content').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
                saveTableContentIntoLocalStorage();
            });
            document.getElementById('load_table_content').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
                loadTableContentFromLocalStorage();
            });
            document.getElementById('empty_table_content').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
                emptyTableContent();
            });
        });


    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <table id="tableLKW">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th style scope="col">position</th>
                <th scope="col">number</th>
                <th scope="col">driver's name</th>
                <th scope="col">vehicle identification</th>
                <th scope="col">status</span></th>
                <th scope="col">phone</th>
                <th scope="col">short code</th>
                <th scope="col">gate</th>
                <th scope="col">empties</th>
                <th scope="col">track</th>
                <th scope="col">priority</th>
                <th scope="col">from</th>
                <th scope="col">to</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody contenteditable="true">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Example Number</td>
                <td>Example Name</td>
                <td>placeholder vehicle identification</td>
                <td>placeholder status</td>
                <td>placeholder number</td>
                <td>placeholder code</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>placeholder empties</td>
                <td>placeholder track</td>
                <td>placeholder priority</td>
                <td>placeholder from</td>
                <td>placeholder to</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Example Number</td>
                <td>Example Name</td>
                <td>placeholder vehicle identification</td>
                <td>placeholder status</td>
                <td>placeholder number</td>
                <td>placeholder code</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>placeholder empties</td>
                <td>placeholder track</td>
                <td>placeholder priority</td>
                <td>placeholder from</td>
                <td>placeholder to</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Example Number</td>
                <td>Example Name</td>
                <td>placeholder vehicle identification</td>
                <td>placeholder status</td>
                <td>placeholder number</td>
                <td>placeholder code</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>placeholder empties</td>
                <td>placeholder track</td>
                <td>placeholder priority</td>
                <td>placeholder from</td>
                <td>placeholder to</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Example Number</td>
                <td>Example Name</td>
                <td>placeholder vehicle identification</td>
                <td>placeholder status</td>
                <td>placeholder number</td>
                <td>placeholder code</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>placeholder empties</td>
                <td>placeholder track</td>
                <td>placeholder priority</td>
                <td>placeholder from</td>
                <td>placeholder to</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button id="save_table_content">SAVE CONTENT</button>
    <button id="load_table_content">LOAD CONTENT</button>
    <button id="empty_table_content">EMPTY CONTENT</button>

</body>
</html>
```